# Socket.io way to identify users after disconnection

Tags: node.js, express, http, socket.io

I am looking to find some way to identify a user by some sort of static ID that carries over even after the disconnect and reconnect. I want something that is immediately available from the socket connection function so that I can immediately disconnect if they are on a blacklist, saving something clientside is not suitable for this.

I have tried things like `socket.handshake`
And all other things I have read on forums, is there a way in the latest version?

Thanks

Comment: The only pieces of identification automatically available with a socket.io connection are cookies (from the browser) and the IP address.  There is no magic, invariant ID for that client.  The IP address has issues when the client is behind something like a corporate proxy.  You can use cookies and they will carry over from connect to disconnect to connect again.  You would have to set the cookie yourself (probably in the initial web page that the socket.io connection comes from).  Once the cookie is set, it will arrive with every socket.io connection from that client.

Comment: Eh, thanks. Can we set the cookies server side through socket.io?

Comment: I don't know if you can set it via socket.io, but you can set it from Express when you serve the web page that contains the socket.io connection code.  If you're using express-session, you can use the session cookie itself as it will already be there.